# Runtime Exception in windows build

Tags: windows-phone-8, codenameone

I am able to generate & install windows phone build in my Microsoft Lumia 640. Its running on Windows OS 8.1.

But as soon as I run application generated by CN1 build server, it gives  error

`An internal application error occurred: java.lang.RuntimeException Unsupported operation` as per below screen shot.
[image]

For a testing purpose I created new CN1 Project and without changing any code / theme.res I just sent windows phone build and it ended up with the same error.

Unfortunately I didnt get any log output from windows phone, as it doesnt support Logcat like Android. Also I tried to grab Isolated Storage by WP Power Tools but there was nothing in it.

Anyone faced / facing this in Codename One windows phone build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows Phone port is the least mature of the Codename One ports having gone thru 3 rewrites due to changes from Microsoft.

We are now debating the 4th rewrite, in the meantime some community members did their own port which should be more complete:
https://github.com/Pmovil/CN1WindowsPort

So as the short answer I suggest using that. For an explanation on how we got here read on.

The reason we didn't already start with the 4th port was Microsofts [project astoria](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3sznwf/ms_possibly_dumping_android_compatibility_for/) that they suddenly (might have) canceled. We were relying on this project for future Windows Phone support but now that its status is unclear we are in a bind.

We also have the JavaScript port & the Windows desktop port as options for targeting windows phone alleviating some of the problem.

If MS cancels the project for good we'll dedicate the resources for a complete rewrite of the port, but that will take time. However, we don't want to start off on such a huge effort and suddenly be faced with a huge shortcut of Android compatibility.